# Java NotSerializableException with custom DataPackage

Tags: java, exception, serialization, stream, notserializableexception

Im currently working on a simple server - client structure for future projects. I decided it would be the best to create my own data-package with custom header-information such as local/public ip, a time stamp etc. The following is the class i came up with:

```
public class DataPackage {
    private Object object;
    private Date time;
    private long timeMs;
    private boolean responded;
    private String publicIp;
    private String internalIp;
    private int hash;

    public DataPackage(Object object) {
        this.object = object;
        this.responded = false;
        this.time = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        this.timeMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.publicIp = this.generatePublicIp();
        this.internalIp = this.generateInternalIp();
        this.hash = System.identityHashCode(this);
    }

    private String generatePublicIp() {
        try {
            URL whatismyip = new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(whatismyip.openStream()));

            return in.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String generateInternalIp() {
        try {
            return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

(I removed the getters and setters)

I decided to use an object so i can send anything in the class. It compiles well but if i try to send a simple string, packaged in the class, i get a NotSerializableException. Are there any attributes or fields which cant be converted to a stream or should i change the class to be generic? Im NOT an expert in streams and networking, so im thankfull for every bit of help and explanation i can get.

NOTE: Im not a native english speaker to please excuse any spelling/grammar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement Serializable interface in order for the class to be transferred over network.

Change first line of your class to :

```
import java.io.Serializable;
public class DataPackage implements Serializable{
```

Comment: :) Happy to help. Please mark the answer as correct. I am a newbie and trying to build my reputation. :P

Answer (score 0):

`java.io.NotSerializableException` is thrown when your object is not serializable that means your `object` or any `non-transient` property of that object does not implement the `Serializable` interface. And in your case, `DataPackage` is not Serializable. `Serializable` is a marker `interface`  which basically tells `JVM` that any `instance` of the `Serializable` type can be serialized. Here you can go through the docs of [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) and [NotSerializableException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/NotSerializableException.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your class should implement the [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface.

Also note that each property of your class, in your case *object* should also implement this interface in order for serialization to work properly.

So I would consider making this class generic to force object to implement Serializable interface.

**EDIT :** for example if you try to serialize a DataPackage that contains a ByteBuffer(which is not Serializable) like this : `new DataPackage(ByteBuffer.allocate(1))`, you will get an Exception.

try this :

```
    import java.io.Serializable;

    public class DataPackage<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable{
    private T object;
    private Date time;
    private long timeMs;
    private boolean responded;
    private String publicIp;
    private String internalIp;
    private int hash;

    public DataPackage(T object) {
        this.object = object;
        this.responded = false;
        this.time = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        this.timeMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.publicIp = this.generatePublicIp();
        this.internalIp = this.generateInternalIp();
        this.hash = System.identityHashCode(this);
    }

    private String generatePublicIp() {
        try {
            URL whatismyip = new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(whatismyip.openStream()));

            return in.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String generateInternalIp() {
        try {
            return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

In this way you can be sure that the objects you are trying to send are all serializable.

If you dont want to use generics than make *object* of type Serializable like this :

```
import java.io.Serializable;

        public class DataPackage implements Serializable{
        private Serializable object;
        private Date time;
        private long timeMs;
        private boolean responded;
        private String publicIp;
        private String internalIp;
        private int hash;

        public DataPackage(Serializable object) {
            this.object = object;
            this.responded = false;
            this.time = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            this.timeMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
            this.publicIp = this.generatePublicIp();
            this.internalIp = this.generateInternalIp();
            this.hash = System.identityHashCode(this);
        }

        private String generatePublicIp() {
            try {
                URL whatismyip = new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com");
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(whatismyip.openStream()));

                return in.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        private String generateInternalIp() {
            try {
                return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```